# string "7\aAZEA\0\a\rPV" sent to a WCF service is received as "7\aAZEA\0\a\nPV"

Tags: c#, string, wcf

When I send the string

> **"7\aAZEA\0\a\rPV"**

to a WCF service it's received as

> **"7\aAZEA\0\a\nPV"**

i.e. the **\r** is changed to **\n**.

I assume this is due to "**/r**" being a control character.

This is an encrypted string so I can't manually replace characters.

How can I prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with "7\\aAZEA\0\\a\\nPV"

Comment: Please include the simplest example code allowing to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: try to send the string with a preceding "@": @"7\aAZEA\0\a\rPV"

Comment: Sending double-backslashes seem to work, so I may use that as a fallback.   I tried prefixing it with @ but it had no effect.   I don't think my code would be useful here asthe issue does not occur 'in' my code: As this requires two programs it is faster to duplicate by sending this string to an empty WCF service and checking the received string.

Comment: Any reason why you are sending control codes like that at all, and not some base64-type of encoded data instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments already helped, but hope this will clarify the reasoning behind it.

In a string a backslash is always used for control characters, `\r` being carriage return, `\n` being a line feed and `\0` being a null character. You are indeed correct, `\r` is being interpreted as a carriage return (which it replaces with the `\n` line feed). Because `\a` does not mean anything, it is sent as two characters (`\` and `a`). To make sure a backslash is interpreted as a backslash in a string (and not possibly as a control character), a double backslash `\\`  is used.

When you require to send other strings, make sure that you use double backslashes everywhere the string actually requires a backslash and the following character to be sent.

In your string `\0` is interpreted as a single NULL character, not the two characters `\` and `0`. This could be what you want, but if not, it's best to write `\\0`.

To conclude, if you want to send your string literally, this is what you should send:

```
"7\\aAZEA\\0\\a\\nPV"
```

Comment: Thanks - \0 was a null character which was why .Replace (@"\",@"\\") wasn't working. I've changed the service so that it will not encrypt the messages for now. If they do need to be encrypted in the future I'll find a less troublesome method of encryption.